# Batch script, How to trim part of a line in a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have this script here to list all the file in a directory and output to Index.txt

```
echo off
for /r %%a in (*) do echo %%a >> Index.txt
```

The script output the whole path like
 C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Folder\somefile.doc

How do I keep only \Documents\Folder\somefile.doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%i in (*) do set a=%%i&set a=!a:C:\Users\Administrator=!&echo !a! >> Index.txt
```

hope this helps, if not can you give more info?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*) do  echo %cd:~22%\%%a >> Index.txt
```

%cd:~22% removes the first 22 characters, which in this case is C:\Users\Administrator, so you will have to change it if your user name is different.

Comment: this will not work with the recursion the OP presented, also very fragile, cannot be reused easily on different accounts.